# Can i use sharepoint 2013 client object model for SP 2010

Tags: sharepoint-online, client-object-model

I am working on a product. Our product is built on top of .NET framework 4.5. We use Sharepoint client object model (v14.0.0.0) for communicating with Sharepoint (both SP 2010 and SP 2013). This works for most of our scenarios. We have customers who use Sharepoint 2010, Sharepoint 2013. Now one of our new customer wants to integrate our product with Sharepoint office 365. For communicating with SP office 365, we need to provide the security token for the COM for communicating with the Sharepoint.

My question is Can I still use SP 2010 COM assembly reference for communication with SP 2010, SP 2013 and Sharepoint Office 365. If “YES” then are there any major drawbacks? Can I use SP 2013 COM assembly reference for communication with SP 2010, SP 2013 and Sharepoint Office 365. If “YES” then are there any major drawbacks?

PS: I understand, it will be clumsy if I maintain separate source code for SP 2010, SP 2013 and office 365. So please suggest the best approach.

Thanks, Mallikarjun

Comment: You get get yourself a copy of CAMLDesigner (it can connect to SP2013 and SP2010), use your favourite disassembler (ILSpy, Reflector, etc.) and see what they do...

Answer (score 1):

I just wrote a blog post about this that may help you: http://sharepointtaproom.com/2014/01/23/connecting-to-sharepoint-onlines-csom-or-rest-apis-from-sharepoint-2010/. In the post I talk about authenticating to SharePoint Online (CSOM and REST APIs) from code running in SharePoint 2010.

Since you asked about drawbacks, one drawback of using the SharePoint 2010 CSOM to work with SharePoint Online is you only have the functionality available that's in the 2010 CSOM (so managed metadata and other features are not available like they are in the 2013 CSOM). One way to work around that is to use the REST API. It's more code to write but also lets you do more against SharePoint Online if your code is running in SharePoint 2010.